# Formidable Not Uploading When Using Multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs, multer

I'm trying to create a page that lets you upload a file to a folder and say what a number is in an input. I'm new to the multer library(which is what I'm using right now) and I usually use body-parser. Here is my app.js and my upload.ejs, I'll explain what my problem is below it.

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const formidable = require('formidable');
const fs = require('fs');
const ejs = require('ejs')
const path = require('path');
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer({ dest: 'upload/'});
const type = upload.any('gradeNumber');

const app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');



app.get('/fileupload', function (req, res) {
    res.render("upload")
});
    


app.post('/fileupload',type, function (req, res) {
    const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    console.log(req.body.gradeNumber);
    form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
        const oldpath = files.filetoupload.path;
        const newpath = 'C:/Users/Shubh Computer/Desktop/VSCode/Grades/1/' + files.filetoupload.name;
        fs.rename(oldpath, newpath, function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            res.write('File uploaded and moved!');
            res.end();
        });
    });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

**upload.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Upload File</title>   
</head>

<body>

<form action="fileupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="filetoupload"><br>
    
    <label>What Grade</label><input type="text" name="gradeNumber"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
                                                                            
</html>
```

Before I started to use multer, I was uploading the file to a specific folder without error, but would get the input value as undefined. After I added the `app.post(/fileupload,type,function(req,res){})` I can log the input but can't upload the file(If I take out the `type` I can still upload the file). I was also wondering what the `const upload = multer({ dest: 'upload/'});` does because I have a folder(not created by me) that holds weird files that Visual Studio can't support(Notepad can't support it either). I have a strong feeling it's something to do with that line, but like I said, I'm new to Multer. If somebody could come up with a solution that can upload and log the value that would be great!(I have spent a long time writing this I'm trying to get my reputation up so my votes can display to the public; I wouldn't mind if you can upvote my post!!)

Comment: Why are you using multipart parsing middleware with a multipart parsing API? You only need one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe start the URL with a / so that the intended URL is returned instead of its parent or child.
It might solve the folder issue.

and about the "type" middelware, I haven't seen yet any example of [upload.any()](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#any) with passing parameters.
I'm new to Multer too, but I think it might solve the problems

Answer (score 0):

You dont need formidable if you use multer middleware. Multer will parse the input form and populate it in req.body as usual.The file data will be populated in req.files.